# Changing the icon colour of individual Navigation Drawer icons

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, tint

This question has been asked before in comments on other threads but no-one has ever got a straight answer as far as I can see.

What I'm looking to do is style every individual icon in a nav draw to be tinted with different colours. Here's an example:

[image: The example]

Using `app:itemIconTint` will style all icons. Is there a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `onCreate()` method put this:

`NavigationView nw = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view); 
 nw.setItemIconTintList(null);`

and then all your icons will be shown in their original color. Basically all you need to create are colored icons.

Answer (score 3):

onCreate methode of Activity

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
//For each icon
navigationView.getMenu()
                .findItem(R.id.home)
                .getIcon()
                .setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```